# How to get informed when Keycloack LDAP-sync fails?

Tags: ldap, synchronization, keycloak

we're using Keycloack with activated LDAP-sync. The LDAP-provider uses a *Custom User LDAP Filter* which filters for department names.

Now there has been a organizational change in the department names, which resulted in no user was able to log into our application.

Is there a technical way, to maybe get a notification via mail, if there large changes in the number of synced users?

Regards
Lars